# Do 3 Dimensional Fractals exist?

Tags: fractals

I understand that certain mathematical sets produce fractals. Are there fractals defined by sets with more than 2 variables? Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, why not?${}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do.  Most fractal constructions can be taken into three dimensions.  One of the easiest to visualize is to make a 3D version of the [Sierpinski carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet).

Take a cube, cut it into $3 \times 3 \times 3$ subcubes, checkerboard color them with the corners black, and remove all the white ones.  Now partition the subcubes you kept and keep going.  The result is [image]

Comment: Also http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Sierpinski_pyramid.png.